# Reading from a field in multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

As far as I understand any thread may create a `thread_local` cache of the variables one's going to read. Also, `volatile` field means any thread that reads the variable will get one's actual value and it doesn't depends on the value cached within the thread. So, should we declare a field as a volatile any time we're going to read one from some threads?

Comment: ThreadLocal variables are only visible from the executing thread. Not the others, so here, the variable definition as volatile is irrelevant

Comment: @andresoviedo, OP is not asking about ThreadLocal objects, but using "thread local" to describe the CPU's local cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`volatile` is used to indicate that a variable's value will be modified by different threads.
So yes you should declare a member volatile if plan to read it from other thread.

Access to volatile variable acts as if it enclosed in synchronized block. So you don't need an explicit synchronization.

Comment: `volatile` does not exactly say that; it says that any write to a variable declared as such _happens-before_ any read from that variable (from the Java memory model); in effect, this means the JVM implementations are forced, one way or another, to ensure that any thread will read the latest value written to that variable (using barriers or whatever mechanims are available for that architecture/language combo)

Comment: @fge Exactly. Instead of quoting I am giving the inference. Do you believe it is wrong?

Comment: Not exactly wrong, but misleading; saying, for instance, that "A volatile variable is never cached into thread local storage" is wrong, since depending on the arch/language combo you may very well read from a thread local storage. I think it is better to describe the _effects_ of `volatile` rather than its implementation, since the latter is (yes, again) arch/language dependent.

Comment: @fge Thanks, rephrased as per your suggestion

Comment: @fge Do you mean that volatile variables are also cached into a thread local storage, but when we read them we'll get actual value (how it's implemented that's not my concern).

Comment: @St.Antario it is entirely dependent on your architecture and the language used by the JVM implementation (and how "deep" said language delves into the architecture); it _may_ happen that for a given implementation and a given set of conditions, reading a `volatile` variable will hit a TLS (Thread Local Storage). But those are entirely implementation details, and you should not care about them, unless you are a JVM implementer yourself. What matters is the happens-before rule; you are guaranteed that time-wise, if you read the variable's value, you are guaranteed to see the latest write to it.